# Can I transfer ETH without syncing on current pc?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets

I have a new pc and want to access the ETH I had in my wallet on my old pc before and send them to poloniex. I have the keystore folder. I downloaded the current Ethereum Wallet (0.8.3) and it started syncing. I realised this would take a couple of days (like before) so closed it and instead ran:

geth --fast --cache=2048 --jitvm
I also replaced the file in keystore with the one I backed up before.
This has run overnight, in the meantime, if I click on "Launch Application" for EW, the balance shows as 0.00. Do I need to sync to be able to get my ETH?

Comment: why not to just copy your Ethereum folder for the old pc to the new one? i posted also an online solution below

Answer (score 7):

You could use https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction to send your funds to poloniex

Follow these instructions:

1-Find your keystore file. (%appdata%/Ethereuem/keystore in windows).

2-Open MyEtherWallet and go to the “Send Ether” tab.

3-Select your keystore file or enter your private key.

4-If a password appears, enter your password and then hit “unlock wallet”.

[image]

5-then go to Go to Poloniex and get a deposit address.

[image]
[image]
6-Go back to MyEtherWallet and paste that deposit address into the “To Address:” field.

7-Enter the amount to send. It is recommended to test with a small amount first.
[image]

Comment: a bit insecure to send your keystore file and private key to MyEtherWallet no?

Comment: Yes there is a risk espicialy if you are a victim of phishing

Answer (score 5):

Let's do this. Suppose you want to send ether from the address `0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d` (the sender) to the address `0xfc7412e818aaed57f792bdc22b94244a1cede7ff` (the receiver).

- Go to Etherscan and see your "sender" address https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d
- Count how many "OUT" transactions there have been. Let's say `5`. That will be your nonce. Alternatively, click on the last transaction, and you will see that its nonce is `4`, which means `5` is your next nonce.
- Go to your Geth console
- Type `personal.unlockAccount("0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d")`, enter your passphrase
- Type `eth.sendTransaction({ from: "0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d", to: "0xfc7412e818aaed57f792bdc22b94244a1cede7ff", value: YOUR_VALUE_IN_WEI, nonce: 5 })`

If all goes according to plan, the transaction will be sent to other nodes, even though your Geth is still synchronising.

---

If it fails, try:

- Type `tx = eth.signTransaction({ from: "0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d", to: "0xfc7412e818aaed57f792bdc22b94244a1cede7ff", value: YOUR_VALUE_IN_WEI, nonce: 5 });`
- You get:

```
> tx;
{
  raw: "0xf868831004cf8504a817c80083015f9094fc7412e818aaed57f792bdc22b94244a1cede7ff01801ba004aff46beeaa154f8d44a0101969c280c664c5c8ff4697e0aca0aa91c979951ca016b258c329aa71ca57358f08ee303a5bc6e27873b1a06ecc36da563eb029634d",
  tx: {
    data: "0x",
    from: "0x8d3dc163f10dd803446937c18be93ad4713cf34d",
    gas: "0x15f90",
    gasPrice: "0x4a817c800",
    hash: "0x17e2d5326c3c629444b6ff2bc01820b01d9c7a743ef9f371c439e4ea1170ab1c",
    nonce: "0x5",
    to: "0xfc7412e818aaed57f792bdc22b94244a1cede7ff",
    value: "0x1" // Actually your Wei value
  }
}
```

- Type `eth.sendRawTransaction(tx.raw)`

Comment: Copying/pasting is messy. Why not use variables?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - in case the geth client is not fully synced (e.g. running in light mode), I get Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You are requried a synced blockchain to send transaction. Your balance shows 0.00 because the address doesn't have ethers at the latest block you have in your sync. If you still have your old pc, you can backup the "chaindata" folder(same directory to keystore) to your new pc(if both are running with geth and same OS) which you don't have to sync the blocks that you were synced before.

Another option is using Parity instead of Ethereum Wallet which can sync the blockchain quickly.

Comment: No, you don't need a synced blockchain to send transactions; you just need to know the correct nonce. The client will try to warn you that there's not enough funds, but you can get around that by signing and sending manually