# "gas required exceeds allowance" with eth.sendTransaction on geth CLI

Tags: go-ethereum, console, cli

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8772/1334).

I do not want to sync so I run

```
./geth-1.9.0 --maxpeers 0 console`
```

and do this:

```
FROM="0x..."
TO="0x..."
ETH_AMOUNT=0.1
NONCE=1

VALUE=web3.toWei(ETH_AMOUNT,"ether")

TX={ from: FROM, to: TO, value: VALUE, nonce: NONCE }

personal.unlockAccount(FROM)
eth.sendTransaction(TX)
```

I get this error

```
WARN [06-30|20:58:39.016] Served eth_sendTransaction               reqid=36 t=5.238384ms   err="gas required exceeds allowance (5003) or always failing transaction"
Error: gas required exceeds allowance (5003) or always failing transaction
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

How do I figure out if the error is "gas required exceeds allowance" or "always failing transaction"?

How do I figure out what the required gas amount and allowance amounts are?

What went wrong?

Comment: provide more gas value during transaction building

Comment: How? And how much?

Answer (score 0):

try to define enough gas in your TX

```
TX={ from: FROM, to: TO, value: VALUE, nonce: NONCE , gas: 3000000 }
```

keep rising the gas value until it works.

Comment: I'm confused between "gas", "gas price", and "gas limit". ethgasstation.info says 1Gwei is "standard", you wrote 3Mwei in your example so I'm wondering if it means the same thing. Does the `gas` property here refer to price, limit, or something else?

Comment: gas : is The amount of gas to use for the transaction (unused gas is refunded)in other words it's the gas you'are wiling to pay for you transaction. Please check the doc https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

Comment: In many places elsewhere I read that "gasUsed=gasPrice*gas" but if unused "gas" is refunded then that usage of "gas" would seem to refer to a limit on "gasUsed" whereas "gas" in the equation would seem to refer to another kind of quantity, measured in a different dimensional unit. Right?

Comment: I mean, if "gasPrice" is measured in wei/some_unit and "gas" is measured in some_unit then "totalGas=gasPrice*gas" is measured in wei which makes sense but what on earth are the units for this "gas" parameter? Because it sure as hell isn't in wei.